# C read contents of file piped in

Tags: c, pipe

I'm trying to do analysis on some data and I am building a few tools that I was hoping to chain together with pipes.

`cat file.dat | ./tool | ./tool2 ...`

But I'm not sure how to read the piped in data. I know it's coming in through stdin, but I can exactly wait for the file end. So I guess I'm looking for something like this:

```
long value;
while(scanf("%ld\n",&value)){
  value2 = do_something(value);
  printf("%ld\n",value2);
}
return 0;
```

But scanf, doesn't return 0 when stdin is "empty" what is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `scanf` returns `EOF` when it reaches the end of file. You can use a code like this to check for that:

```
while (1) {
    long value;
    int ret = scanf("%ld\n", &value);
    if (ret == EOF) {
        break;
    }
    printf("%ld\n", value);
}
```

See the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for more details.